# Add button next to Search bar inside Bootstrap Header

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have created a responsive Bootstrap header having Name in the left corner, search bar and dropdown list in the right hand corner. Now I'm trying to add a button on the left hand side of the searchbar but not being able to..

**Js fiddle**   https://jsfiddle.net/Lucy1/qn0r10th/4/

**HTML code**..

```
     <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" id="header">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar1">
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>                        
                </button>
                <a href="index.html" class="navbar-brand" id="icon"><b>Sample Name</b></a>
            </div>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar1">

                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right" id="navbar1right">
                    <li class="dropdown" id="subheader">
                         <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu" id="dropA">
                         <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>

                <form class="navbar-form navbar-right" role="search" id="navBarSearchForm" type=get action="myindex.html">
      <div class="input-group" id ="searchA">
      <button onclick="storeYourStuff()" id="button_top_right" class="btn btn-primary">StoreYourStuff</button>
                    <input id="wish_title1" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search Website" name="wish_title1"></input>
                            <span class="input-group-btn">
                                <button class="btn btn-primary"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i></button>
                            </span>
                </div>

                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
```

I'm trying to add a button before the searchbar inside the form tag but not able to. Can't figure out where I'm going wrong.. Please help

Comment: I want a button, searchbar and a dropdown in that order in the right corner of the header.

Comment: put your button outside button group https://jsfiddle.net/3m8Lsxef/

Comment: did any of the answers work for you?

Answer (score 0):

Your button is in the wrong place, it needs to be outside of the button-group:

**Working Fiddle**: [Link](https://jsfiddle.net/71m4ywad/)

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" id="header">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar1">
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>                        
                    </button>
                    <a href="index.html" class="navbar-brand" id="icon"><b>Sample Name</b></a>
                </div>
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar1">

                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right" id="navbar1right">
                        <li class="dropdown" id="subheader">
                             <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu" id="dropA">
                             <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                    </ul>

                    <form class="navbar-form navbar-right" role="search" id="navBarSearchForm" type=get action="myindex.html">

          <button onclick="storeYourStuff()" id="button_top_right" class="btn btn-primary">StoreYourStuff</button>
          <div class="input-group" id ="searchA">
                        <input id="wish_title1" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search Website" name="wish_title1">
                                <span class="input-group-btn">
                                    <button class="btn btn-primary"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i></button>
                                </span>
                    </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

The button should be  placed inside a proper span

```
<form class="navbar-form navbar-right" role="search" id="navBarSearchForm" type=get action="myindex.html">
      <div class="input-group" id ="searchA">
      <span class="input-group-btn"><button onclick="storeYourStuff()" id="button_top_right" class="btn btn-primary">StoreYourStuff</button></span>

                    <input id="wish_title1" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search Website" name="wish_title1">
                            <span class="input-group-btn">
                                <button class="btn btn-primary"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i></button>
                            </span>
                </div>
                </form>
```

Comment: Is there a way of putting space between the button and searchbar?? and also make button appear below searchbar in small screen sizes??

Comment: for th space this fiddle seems right https://jsfiddle.net/71m4ywad/2/ ... for appearing below the searchbar  .i don't know .

Comment: Is there a way of adding space by using span like you have done in your answer??

Comment: I hope my answer and comments are useful to you